# How do I execute a shell command, and assign the output to an AC_DEFINE variable in configure.ac

Tags: bash, automake, autoreconf

I need to identify the major version of a software, to do this it's principally to execute

> command --version | head | awk -F "." '{print $1}'

Now, i need to assign this output to a AC_DEFINE variable.

I've tried;

> majorvar=$(command --version | head | awk -F "." '{print $1}')
>
> AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([myVar],["$majorvar"],[description])

here 'command' appeared in the resulting config.h file

and

> AC_DEFINE([myVar],0,[descr])
>
> AC_SUBST([myVar],[$(command --version | head | awk -F "." '{print $1}')])

where the value set by the define (0) is appearing in the result.

Is it possible to obtain the result that I want, i.e

#define myVar 5

or am I going about this in the wrong way, and if so, how should I go about it?

BR/Patrik

Comment: Why the `head` command? You can use this: `command --version | awk -F "." 'NR==1{print $1;exit}'`

Comment: @hek2mgl No need for `NR==1` if you are going to exit immediately.

Comment: Does using backticks instead of `$()` change anything?

Comment: @EtanReisner Are you sure that awk will not continue iterating over the whole file and performing `NR==1` checks? (which will result in `false` of course)

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't understand the question. You are using `exit` in that block to tell awk to stop processing the file. That means you stop after the first line. (`NR==1` is true at that point but why test it?)

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh now got it. You are right, I can omit the test and simply exit... Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed several month to wrap my head around the concept of macros.
As the name already tells, macros are 'bigger' than scripts. I hope this example can help.

```
AC_DEFUN([VERSION],
[$(test -f $srcdir/VERSION && cat $srcdir/VERSION || AS_ECHO(["$PACKAGE_VERSION"]); )])

am_stable_version_rx='[[1-9]\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?]'
am_beta_version_rx="[$am_stable_version_rx[bdfhjlnprtvxz]]"

am_release_type=`AS_ECHO(["$VERSION"]) | LC_ALL=C awk ["
  /^$am_stable_version_rx$/ { print \"stable\"; exit(0); }
  /^$am_beta_version_rx$/ { print \"beta version\"; exit(0); }
  { print \"development snapshot\"; }"]`

test "$am_release_type" = stable || cat <<EOF

WARNING: You are about to use a $am_release_type of AC_PACKAGE_NAME VERSION.
WARNING: It might easily suffer from new bugs or regressions.
WARNING: You are strongly advised not to use it in production code.

Please report bugs, problems and feedback to <AC_PACKAGE_BUGREPORT>.
EOF
```

The code snippet defines:

1. a macro function DEFUN named VERSION
2. a script variable with regex for versioning
3. a script variable assignment containing a macro AS_ECHO which places the VERSION script during the generation of the configure script.